# Code update not reflected in Django apps behavior. Why is this happening and what can be done to fix this issue?

Tags: python, django, nginx

**Problem summary**

I’m trying to get a Django applications code to update on the server it’s running on. I’ve already uploaded the updated code (a `.py` file) but the updated code is not being displayed in the behavior of the application. Ive already tried several attempts to solve this problem. I will go over these attempts below and hopefully this will help diagnose what I need to do.

**Here are some additional details about the application to help give context to the problem.**

- I am not the developer who wrote the application, I was hired for maintenance and updates. Sadly there was no documentation given and very little code commenting.
- Im still a little green when it comes to Django.
- This problem is occurring on a production server so care must be taken to minimize downtime. Because of the 2 reasons above I am not totally confident that I can restart the server if it goes down.
- Django version: 1.7
- Servers being used:  gunicorn + nginx

The way the application works is simple. A user places an order and this triggers an email to be sent. The code I changed is also simple. An additional html paragraph was added to the string containing the emails content. When the application is tested this new string is not added. The code is not updating.

**Directory Structure for Application**

I am replacing the applications name with *appname*

**root folder**

```
appname
py2_appname
staticfiles
```

**py2_appname**

this contains included packages and binaries

```
bin
include
lib
local
```

**appname folder**

This contains the application code

```
├── accounts
│   └── migrations
├── admin_keys
├── emails
├── errors
│   └── migrations
├── main_site
│   └── migrations
├── appname
│   └── __pycache__
├── appname_admin
│   └── migrations
├── promotions
│   └── migrations
├── signaling
│   ├── migrations
│   └── templates
│       └── signal_email
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── email
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── thumbnails
│   └── js
│       └── locales
├── templates
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── errors
│   ├── _layouts
│   ├── mainsite
│   ├── appname_admin
│   └── test
└── testing
    └── migrations
```

**Ive already made a few attempts to solve this problem.**

1. Delete the original compiled file. This would force a new one to be generated when the script generating the email is executed. This did not happen. A new .pyc file was not created. The application is still functioning as it always has. This seems to imply the executing code it cached somewhere.

   ```
   Here are the original files:
   -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 47872 Jul 13 04:39 admin_email.py 
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   48212 Feb 10 03:12 admin_email.pyc
   ```
2. Another suggestion was to modify the applications wsgi file last modified meta field by executing the command: touch . This updates the last modified time to the current time but leaves the contents of the file unchanged. This did not work but maybe Im not updating the correct file. The file Im updating is called: wsgi.py. It is in the appname folder (see above)

**Here are the contents of wsgi.py**

```
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "appname.settings")

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In the settings.py file, which is also in the appname folder, there is only 1 line of code that mention of the wsgi:

```
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appname.wsgi.application'
```

Is this the correct file to apply touch to so that my server applies the code changes?

3. Restart the server. This is have not attempted yet. As mentioned above this is a production server. I’m not certain I can start application correctly if it goes down. Perhaps someone could give advice about this. Here is some more info about the server and application:

**Process running on server (from ps -aux, command column)**

```
    /path/to/appenv/py2_appname/bin/python /opt/www/py2_appname/bin/gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3
    /path/to/appenv/py2_appname/bin/python /opt/www/py2_appname/bin/gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3
    /path/to/appenv/py2_appname/bin/python /opt/www/py2_appname/bin/gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3
    /path/to/appenv/py2_appname/bin/python /opt/www/py2_appname/bin/gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3
    nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
    nginx: worker process
    nginx: worker process
    nginx: worker process
    nginx: worker process
```

Notice that gunicorn is running from py2_appname. This is a folder one level above appname and contains the binaries used in the application.

Comment: By restart the serrver...did you restart gunicorn? i work on uwsgi and after i update my code i need to restart the server.

Comment: yes, I'd appreciate any suggestions  on how to restart `gunicorn`. I'm hoping that will update how the application is working. Please note the `gunicorn` processes shown above. If I need to restart Id like to be able to get the same processes running. Since this is a prod server I want to be 100% sure Ill be able to correctly restart.

Comment: http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html

Comment: Also, check supervisor http://supervisord.org/configuration.html You should be able to restart the process from there

Comment: Ok so perhaps the command is exactly what is shown from `ps: /path/to/appenv/py2_appname/bin/python /opt/www/py2_appname/bin/gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3`

Comment: `supervisor` is not installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting the script `admin_email.py` to recompile is to restart `gunicorn`. This can be done with the `killall` command. To restart `gunicorn` execute:

```
gunicorn appname.wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=3 --daemon
```

This must be executed from the directory the django script `manage.py` is executed from.